# not able to get $(this).attr('name') in jquery

Tags: jquery, events

I am working on events and using the bind technique as follows

```
$(".floor").bind('click.index',
{page:'floor.php',get:'floor='+$(this).attr('name')},loadContent);
```

So what I am doing here is this, I am trying to attach a click event to class .floor and later in the function loadContent, I am making a ajax request according to the e.data.page and e.data.get variables.

But when I actually execute it, the url is as follows
floor.php?floor=undefined

Please help me get out of this problem

Answer (score 3):

When you pass data to your handler function, you should note that `$(this)` doesn't refer to the jQuery object in that context. In other words, `$(this)` refers to `window` object (or any other object other than jQuery object, based on the context), wrapped in jQuery. Thus, you should use `$(this)` inside your callback function.

```
$(".floor").bind('click.index', {page:'floor.php'}, function(e){
   var name = $(this).attr('name');
});
```

Comment: I am trying to use a namespace with my event, so I can destroy it easily. And bind uses a optional data argument.                     The link to namespaced events http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events

Comment: This answer is wrong, except the last paragraph. `click.index` is a namespaced event as the OP noted, and `bind` can accept a Javascript object (not JSON, that is a different thing) as its second parameter. Please read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) before spreading wrong info.

Comment: I updated the answer @bazmegakapa. You too read the whole answer before writing comments ;).

Comment: @SaeedNeamati I've read the whole answer, as my comment proves. I will remove my downvote, because you removed false information. The problem I have now, is that we cannot be sure that `this` refers to the `window` object. It depends on the code, it can refer to anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$(this)` is being executed **when the function is bound**, not when the handler (loadContent) is called. When it's bound, `this` most likely refers to the window object. You don't have access to the event target at binding time.

I would probably restructure your code to not pass in custom event data, and instead modify the `loadContent` function to look something like

```
function loadContent(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target),
        data;
    if($target.hasClass('floor')) {
        data = {page: ...};
    } else {
        data = ...;
    }
    ... ajax shenanigans 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when using `this`, always think it through what does it refer to.

```
$(".floor").bind(
    'click.index',
    {
         page: 'floor.php',
         get: 'floor=' + $(this).attr('name')
    },
    loadContent
);
```

In this code snippet, `this` will not refer to what you think it will refer to (`.floor` jQuery object). It is impossible to tell what it refers to now, depends on your code around this snippet. You can read about `this` for example [on Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).

You will have to take care of assigning the value of `name` *inside* your event handler, where `this` refers to `.floor`.

```
function loadContent (e) {
    ...
    var getFull = e.data.get + $(this).attr('name')
    ...
}
```

For this to work, you only have to change the way you pass your `get`:

```
{
     page: 'floor.php',
     get: 'floor='
},
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XNaYk/)